# I want to design a screen which will show different number of videos on same screen based on certain condition

Tags: ios, swift, dynamiclayout

This is an iOS problem.
I want to design a screen which will show a video on full screen. After some time based on some backend condition if another video is available I have to show that by splitting the screen into two vertical halves. After some time if one more video is available I have to again split the screen and show the third video horizontally on the bottom of the screen.

I am new to iOS and I am not able to manage the screen split on runtime based on backend condition.  please help me in this regard.

Comment: Actually, I want to design a screen which should show video like in a skype video conference call. Like in skype when the number of users increase in call the screen adapts to it and shows all video feeds.

Comment: Actually, I have this design requirement and I am not able to accomplish it. so I thought I can get a little help here.

Comment: You could use a `UIStackView` for this, I am not posting a detailed answer, because I got downvoted immediately. You could take a look at the documentation for futher details: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview

Answer (score 1):

Using AVPlayer it possible to play multiple videos in a view. You can use Apple's [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer).

> An AVPlayer is a controller object used to manage the playback and
>   timing of a media asset. You can use an AVPlayer to play local and
>   remote file-based media, such as QuickTime movies and MP3 audio files,
>   as well as audiovisual media served using HTTP Live Streaming.

Comment: Actually I need help in designing the dynamic screen layout. I know how to play video using Avplayer